# How to Change to current user's directory in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How is it possible to change to a user default directory

Is there a default variable that can be used e.g. %USER%

would return: C:\Users\MyUsername

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [`%HOMEPATH%`](http://environmentvariables.org/index.php?title=HomePath).

So:

```
CD %HOMEPATH%
```

Comment: Please note that this does not include the drive on which the home directory is located. For this, use `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`, which makes "X:\Users\MyUser" where X is the correct drive.

Answer (score 34):

Use [`%UserProfile%`](http://environmentvariables.org/index.php?title=UserProfile).

```
cd /D %UserProfile%
```

[/D : change the current DRIVE in addition to changing folder.](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)

Comment: What if I have wrong drive active and I don't want to hard code `C:` for example?

Comment: Use the `/D` parameter.